# complex url trouble, I need a public validator

Tags: validation, url

I have a complex url that in some cases results in a `403 forbiden page` I am prety sure it is OK and the problem is on ISP apache configuration.
So the question is: is there a public and reliable `URL checker`, similar to the "W3C Markup Validation Service" that checks url RFC compliant ???
Thanks a lot.

**Update**
I need an easy way to show to three party guys (the ISP) that the url is Ok
The url is on the comments (I will delete it after I have a solution)
The full php code is nothing:  `<?php   ?>` just to test.

Comment: might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for the syntax of a URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax

EDIT:

Here's your problem:

You have the phrase "search engine optimiz" in your URL, and it's catching that and forbidding it.

This is barred: http://example.com/oo/test_long_url.php?junk=search+engine+optimiz

This is allowed: http://example.com/oo/test_long_url.php?junk=search+engine+optimis

Comment: good!!!! you have reduced de problem to a tiny url but I can't understud what is bad in one case and good in other, provided that the unique diferece is a `z` or `s` letter

Comment: @LuisSiquot, they're filtering on the phrase "search engine optimiz", so it doesn't matter whether it's .php or .htm or another file extension. It's not a matter of `s` or `z` on the end, it's whether the url has the phrase "search engine optimiz" in it.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, thanks a lot! The ISP has removed the rule(s) when I asked for that

Answer (score 0):

This is not an anwser to the question but, it was the fix for my problem. I am posting here just in case that it is useful for someone.

`the url which is displaying an 403 page, occurs because it is triggering a mod_security rule`